# Как написать функцию которая будет складывать одинаковые значение ключей в словарях?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно написать код, в котором будет функция которая складывает значение похожих ключей из двух словарей, но я не знаю как написать данную функцию, помогите, заранее спасибо.
Вот код который надо дополнить этой функцией:

```
def print_shopping_list(pizza, salad):
# здесь код функции которая должна складывать значения похожих ключей в списках
# P.S для начало нужно перевести словари в множества методом set() и сохранить в переменной

pizza = {'мука, кг': 1,
     'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
     'шампиньоны, кг': 1.5,
     'сыр, кг': 0.8,
     'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
     'дрожжи, г': 50}

salad = {'огурцы, кг': 1,
     'перцы, кг': 1,
     'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
     'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
     'листья салата, кг': 0.4}

print_shopping_list(pizza, salad)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def print_shopping_list(pizza, salad):

    pizza_keys, salad_keys = pizza.keys(), salad.keys()
    set_of_products, total_dict = set(pizza_keys).union(set(salad_keys)), {}

    for element in set_of_products:
        if element in pizza_keys and element in salad_keys:
            total_dict[element] = pizza[element] + salad[element]
        elif element in pizza_keys:
            total_dict[element] = pizza[element]
        else:
            total_dict[element] = salad[element]

    for key in total_dict:
        print('{} - {}'.format(key, total_dict[key]))
```

Comment: Вот всё подробно
Задание:

Если вам надо 5 кг помидоров для салата и 3 кг для супа, вы сразу покупаете 8 килограммов.
Напишите функцию, которая напечатает на экран, какие продукты надо купить, и сколько их нужно. Информацию о каждом ингредиенте выводите на отдельной строке в формате: огурцы, кг: 1.5. Каждый продукт должен присутствовать в выводе только один раз.

Comment: А подсказка для кода говорит следующие:
1) Код функции начинайте с создания множества уникальных названий продуктов. Вызовите функцию set(), передав ей как аргумент ключи объекта dish1.
2) Объедините результат методом union() с множеством ключей словаря dish2. Так вы дополните сет названий ингредиентов первого блюда теми ингредиентами, что есть во втором.
3) Для каждого элемента множества уникальных названий:
проверьте оператором in наличие такого ключа в словарях dish1 и dish2, при наличие сложить в какой-нибудь переменной

Comment: понял, ща попробуем

Comment: Скрины прикреплять можно?

Comment: насколько помню нет, ссылки на них можно

Comment: Чекай: https://priscree.ru/img/e22994df74bcda.jpg . вроде всё получилось, но почему то пишет что нет, может разберешься

Comment: https://discord.gg/UtZesk
давай тут

Comment: Эх блин а микро то у меня нету( Или это чат какой то?

Comment: да можем и в чате, но мне кажется ты просто забыл пробел после :

Comment: И правда, это яндекс практикум такой, что точность вывода должна быть в точности до пробела или буквы "е" и "ё"

Comment: ну рад что помог, удачи)

Comment: Как за тебя проголосовать тут или что то в этом роде?)

Comment: галочка слева от ответа)))

Answer (score 2):

Как то у всех сложно, 4 строчки вышло.

```
def print_shopping_list(pizza, salad):

for key in pizza.keys():
     if key in salad.keys():
        pizza[key] = pizza[key] + salad[key]

return pizza

pizza = {'flour': 1,
         'tomatoes': 1.5,
         'shamp': 1.5,
         'cheese': 0.8,
         'olive_oil': 0.1,
         'yeast': 50}

salad = {'cucumber': 1,
         'paper': 1,
         'tomatoes': 1.5,
         'olive_oil': 0.1,
         'salad': 0.4}
print_shopping_list(pizza,salad)
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение для произвольного количества словарей, используя `collections.Counter`.

***Пример:***

```py
from collections import Counter


def get_shopping_list(*args):
    lists = [Counter(d) for d in args]

    result = Counter()
    for d in lists:
        result += d

    return dict(result)


def main():
    pizza = {
        'мука, кг': 1,
        'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
        'шампиньоны, кг': 1.5,
        'сыр, кг': 0.8,
        'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
        'дрожжи, г': 50,
    }
    salad = {
        'огурцы, кг': 1,
        'перцы, кг': 1,
        'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
        'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
        'листья салата, кг': 0.4,
    }

    shopping_list = get_shopping_list(pizza, salad)
    print(shopping_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
{'мука, кг': 1, 'помидоры, кг': 3.0, 'шампиньоны, кг': 1.5, 'сыр, кг': 0.8, 'оливковое масло, л': 0.2, 'дрожжи, г': 50, 'огурцы, кг': 1, 'перцы, кг': 1, 'листья салата, кг': 0.4}
```

Comment: Имортировать библиотеки нельзя, менять код нельзя, нужно дописать ТОЛЬКО функцию не меняя остальной код

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_shopping_list(pizza, salad):
    dish1 = set(pizza)
    dish2 = set(salad)
    full_dish = dish1.union(dish2)

    weight = 0
    for ingridient in full_dish:
        if ingridient in salad and ingridient in pizza:
            weight = pizza[ingridient] + salad[ingridient]

        elif ingridient not in salad:
            weight = pizza[ingridient]
        elif ingridient not in pizza:
            weight = salad[ingridient]
        print(ingridient + ': ' + str(weight))



print_shopping_list(pizza, salad)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_shopping_list(dish1,dish2):
    l1 = set(dish1.keys())
    l2 = set(dish2.keys())
    list = l1.union(l2)
    for i in list:
        weight = 0
        if i in dish1.keys():
        weight += dish1[i]
        if i in dish2.keys():
        weight += dish2[i]
        print(i + ': ' + str(weight))



pizza = {'мука, кг': 1,
     'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
     'шампиньоны, кг': 1.5,
     'сыр, кг': 0.8,
     'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
     'дрожжи, г': 50}
salad = {'огурцы, кг': 1,
     'перцы, кг': 1,
     'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
     'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
     'листья салата, кг': 0.4}

print_shopping_list(pizza, salad)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_shopping_list(val1, val2):
    new_dict1={} #сумма одинаковых продуктов
    for i in val1:
        if i in val2:
            new_dict1[i]=val1[i]+val2[i]
    print(new_dict1)

    new_dict2=val1 #объединение двух данных списков в новый, уникальный
    for j in val2:
        if j not in new_dict2:
            new_dict2[j]=val2[j]
    print(new_dict2)

    new_dict3=new_dict2 #замена значений в уникальном списке на сумму одинаковых продуктов
    for m in new_dict1:
        new_dict3[m]=new_dict1[m]
    print(new_dict3)

    for n in new_dict3:
        print('{}: {}'.format(n, new_dict3[n]))

print_shopping_list(val1, val2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_shopping_list(pizza,salad):
general = {}
for product,weight in pizza.items():
    for product2,weight2 in salad.items():
        if product==product2:
            general[product]=round(weight2+weight,2)
pizza.update(salad)
pizza.update(general)
# set(pizza)
for product,weight in pizza.items():
    print(product+':',weight)
pizza = {'мука, кг': 1,
     'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
     'шампиньоны, кг': 1.5,
     'сыр, кг': 0.8,
     'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
     'хрень': 15,
     'дрожжи, г': 50}
salad = {'огурцы, кг': 1,
     'перцы, кг': 1,
     'хрень': 15.2,
     'помидоры, кг': 2.44,
     'оливковое масло, л': 0.21,
     'листья салата, кг': 0.4}

print_shopping_list(pizza, salad)
```

Еще один способ. Все работает, но проверку не проходит.