# Подскажите, по задаче

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если вам надо 5 кг помидоров для салата и 3 кг для супа, вы сразу покупаете 8 килограммов.
Напишите функцию, которая напечатает на экран, какие продукты надо купить, и сколько их нужно. Информацию о каждом ингредиенте выводите на отдельной строке в формате: огурцы, кг: 1.5. Каждый продукт должен присутствовать в выводе только один раз.

```py
pizza = {'мука, кг': 1,
         'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
         'шампиньоны, кг': 1.5,
         'сыр, кг': 0.8,
         'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
         'дрожжи, г': 50}
salad = {'огурцы, кг': 1,
         'перцы, кг': 1,
         'помидоры, кг': 1.5,
         'оливковое масло, л': 0.1,
         'листья салата, кг': 0.4}

print_shopping_list(pizza, salad)
```

Для себя понимаю, что алгоритм, такой... Из первого словаря берем ключи и создаем множество. Объединяем с ключами из второго словаря. Получается множество уникальных ключей из двух словарей.

```py
piz = set(pizza.keys())
sal = set(salad.keys())
p = piz.union(sal)
```

Пробегаем циклом for по полученному множеству.. и проверяем данный продукт на наличие в обоих исходных словарях. И если этот продукт есть, то складываем в переменную. Каким образом можно, пробежав по двум словарям, сложить это в одну переменную?

Comment: В группе не поделились решением? Простите за сарказм, но это идеальный дубликат: [Как написать функцию которая будет складывать одинаковые значение ключей в словарях?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1031616/339283)

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрите такую логику - если ключ уже существует, то увеличить соответствующее значение, иначе создать ключ со значением. Получается, что достаточно одного словаря.